# How to deliver username and password with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, proxy

I tried for several hours, to deliver my username and my password with query.
I found different answers like

```
$.ajax({        
username: "user",
password: "password",
url: "http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S",
type: "GET",
dataType:'json',
success: function() {alert('blub');},
error: function(){alert('nein!');}, });
```

and

```
$.ajax({        
url: "http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S",
success: function() {alert('blub');},
error: function(){alert('nein!');},
beforeSend: function(xhr){
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic c2Nod1bm5zmRlbGbg0K")},    
});
```

and

```
$('#test1').load('http://c2odWhbm5zmlbGpgOK@de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S');
```

and several more, but neither of them is working.
Can anybody help?
Please!!! I´m despaired!!!

Maybe I should be more specific.
If I try to open the document I get the Error ""NetworkError: 407 Proxy Authentication Required - http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S""
So I think the username and password isn´t delivered right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid the SOP that @jk mentioned you would likely need a server side script (on your host) to load the external url and return the data to your client side script.

**Edit:** to add re your comment.

I'm a .Net guy so my PHP help will be limited. I think you can use CURL to consume external web resources in PHP and I'm assuming that CURL can pass in credentials on a post. Your javascript would have to post to your PHP file, which would post to wikipedia and return whatever you needed to the javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I think thats the problem, but how can I create a server side script? I installed XAMPP and google said I have to create a PHP-file, but what should I write in there?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a violation of the same origin policy:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject 
>   to the same origin policy; 
>   the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.
>   Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

Comment: The JavaScript is also massively off but your absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Although I advice you to be very careful with your password, and not to store it inside a publicly accessible (html/js) file, here's my 10 cents on this.

For this Wikipedia site, a login happens like this:

A POST transaction is made to:

```
http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spezial:Anmelden&action=submitlogin&type=login&returnto=S
```

The following parameters are sent:

- wpName:blablabla
- wpPassword:blablabla
- wpCentralLogin:1
- wpLoginAttempt:Anmelden
- wpLoginToken:bignumberthingythatwillprobablybedifferenteachtime

Hope that will get you going.